# Drawing a whisker between two disparate points in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

So I have some data and I wanted to show the difference between two points for the same thing. Example, I have a package of popcorn that costs 0.48 and .78 somewhere else and I wanted to draw a whisker between the two showing the difference in the two prices and the subsequent gap between them.

My first attempt to do this used the item group plotted against the average cost (since there could be multiple lower and upper prices) then I just plotted this since I am fairly new to tableau. This resulted in a graph that was not nearly what I wanted and just showed lines for each product.

I think what I will eventually need is to plot the average price (I don't know how to combine the two prices to get the overall average) and then plot a whisker which is + or - the average variance in cost (which is another field in the excel sheet.)

I recognize I don't have much code to show but I believe that this is the nature of tableau and I just need to find the proper tools to use within the application. I apologize if this isn't the case, but this is my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are describing a dumbbell chart. There are several ways to make them with Tableau. This post shows a couple appraoches
https://playfairdata.com/tableau-201-how-to-make-dumbbell-charts/